# Modify the Bootstrap modal as per the requirement mentioned

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The problem statement is:
When a user clicks on *select Attribute* a modal should open and it should look like

### Modal Header :

```
Select Attributes:            Select All(Checkbox)                         X(close)
```

### Modal Body

In the modal body,

1. There should be all the checkboxes and every row should have 3 checkboxes only.
2. There should also be a *show more* option button and checkboxes for which should be hidden and when a user clicks on that button, the hidden checkbox should be open below (in the code snippet provided by me, it is opening beside the button) and these checkboxes should be also in same pattern like 3 checkboxes in a row.
3. Then below of it, there should be heading "Japan Attribute" and then checkboxes "ja1", "ja2", "ja3" that should come under this heading. Again the pattern should be same like 3 checkboxes in a row.

### Modal Footer

4. It should have *Ok* and *Cancel* buttons
5. When a user clicks on the *Ok* button, the modal should close and if they again click on *select Attribute*, the modal should open but previously selected checkboxes should not be unchecked.
6. When user clicks on the *Cancel* button, the modal should close and if they again click on *select Attribute*, the modal should open but previously selected checkboxes should be unchecked.

```js
const select = document.getElementById("selectAttribute");
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

select.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const form = document.getElementById("checkbox-form");
  form.reset();
  modal.style.display = "block";
});

function toggleOptions() {
  var optionsDiv = document.getElementById("options");
  if (optionsDiv.style.display === "none") {
    optionsDiv.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    optionsDiv.style.display = "none";
  }
}

const showMoreButton = document.getElementById("show-more");
const checkboxGrid = document.querySelector(".checkbox-grid1");

showMoreButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  checkboxGrid.classList.toggle("show-more-options");
});
```

```css
.popup-modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 54%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 1070px;
}

.popup-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 850px;
}

.modal-buttons {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.checkbox-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.checkbox-grid>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.checkbox-grid>div>label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#selectAttribute {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup-body {
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.options-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.checkbox-grid1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.option {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#show-more {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#show-more:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show-more-options {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="input-group-prepend selectBox multiselect" id="openPopup">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="selectAttribute">Select attributes</span>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="popup-modal">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <div class="modal-header" style="padding: 0rem 0rem;">
      <h4>Select Attributes:</h4>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="select-all" name="options" value="select-all">
        <label for="select-all" style="color: #4e73df"><strong>Select All</strong></label>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <form id="checkbox-form" class="checkbox-grid">
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ch1" name="Status" value="option1">
            <label for="ch1">Status</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ch2" name="Last Updated Timestamp in Live Repo" value="option2">
            <label for="ch2">Last </label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ch3" name="Score" value="option3">
            <label for="ch3">Score</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="button" id="show-more" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="toggleOptions()">Show More Options</button>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group options-container">
            <div id="options" class="checkbox-grid1" style="display: none;">

              <div class="option">
                <input type="checkbox" id="ch34" name="Sunday Opening Time" value="option34">
                <label for="ch34">opt1</label>
              </div>
              <div class="option">
                <input type="checkbox" id="ch35" name="Sunday Closing Time" value="option35">
                <label for="ch35">opt2</label>
              </div>
              <div class="option">
                <input type="checkbox" id="ch36" name="Monday Opening Time" value="option36">
                <label for="ch36">opt3</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <hr>
          <h5 style="color: #4e73df">Japan Attributes: </h5>
          <hr>
          <hr>
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ch11" name="Primary Name (ja)" value="option11">
            <label for="ch11">ja1</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ch12" name="Primary Name (Translation ja-Kana)" value="option12">
            <label for="ch12">ja2</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ch13" name="options" value="option13">
            <label for="ch13">ja3</label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <div class="modal-buttons" style="margin-top: 4px;">
        <input type="submit" id="ok-btn" class="btn btn-success" value="Ok">
        <input type="button" id="cancel-btn" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.show-more').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.more-options').toggle('show');
});

$('.btn-cancel').on('click', function(e) {
   $('.more-options').toggle('show');
   $("#checkbox-form").trigger("reset");
});
```

```css
 .show-more {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding: 8px 0;
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .more-options {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .title {
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #4e73df;
      text-align: center;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 12px 0;
      grid-gap: 22px;
    }
    
    .title:after,
    .title:before {
      content: " ";
      display: block;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #4e73df;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>


  <div class="container pt-5">
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
        Select Attributes
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

          <div class="modal-header d-flex flex-row">
            <div class="flex-fill">
              <h1 class="modal-title fs-6">Select Attributes:</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-fill form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="selectAll">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="selectAll"><strong style="color: #4e73df">Select All</strong></label>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-fill d-flex align-items-end">
              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">

            <form action="" method="post" id="checkbox-form">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-check col-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ch1" value="status">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="ch1">Status</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ch2" value="last_updated">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="ch2">Last Updated</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ch3" value="score">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="ch3">Score</label>
              </div>

              <!-- <div class="form-check col-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ch4" value="score">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="ch4">Score 1</label>
              </div>

              <div class="form-check col-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ch5" value="score">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="ch5">Score 2</label>
              </div> -->

            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="show-more">Show more options >></a>
          </div>

          <div class="container-fluid more-options">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-check col-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ch4" value="1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="ch4">Option 1</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ch5" value="2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="ch5">Option 2</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ch6" value="3">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="ch6">Option 3</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="container-fluid pt-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 p-0">
                <h1 class="title">Japan Attributes</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ja1" value="ja1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="ja1">ja1</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ja2" value="ja2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="ja2">ja2</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check col-4">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ja3" value="ja3">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="ja3">ja3</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-cancel" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is small I require , 
1. The checkboxes should not be one below another , It should be in a row like 3 checkboxes should there in a row .If the count is more than three then it should come in 2nd row
2. When user click on Show more options then theses option should open below it not above the heading(It should be again 3 in a row)

Comment: @TheTester please check the updated snippet and mark it as answer if this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

You have bootstrap and it appears you are working too hard to do it manually in the CSS etc. here.  Here I added some classes and did some slight HTML changes and removed nearly all the CSS.  I also move the event instantiation from the HTML to the JavaScript.

NOTE: I did not wire up the X or OK or Cancel buttons but that is methinks another question and likely something you can do fairly easily given this example.

```js
const select = document.getElementById("selectAttribute");

select.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const form = document.getElementById("checkbox-form");
  const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  form.reset();
  modal.classList.toggle('d-none', false);
  modal.classList.toggle('d-block', true);
});
document.getElementById("myModal").addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', () => {
  document.getElementById('select-all')
    .focus();
});
document.getElementById('show-more').addEventListener("click", function() {
  const optionsDiv = document.getElementById("options-group");
  optionsDiv.classList.toggle('d-none')
  optionsDiv.classList.toggle('d-block');
});
```

```css
.modal-container {
  /* super center the modal */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal-body .modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

#selectAttribute {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="input-group-prepend selectBox multiselect" id="openPopup">
  <span class="input-group-text" id="selectAttribute">Select attributes</span>
</div>
<div class="modal-container ">
  <div id="myModal" class="popup-modal d-none modal container-fluid">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4>Select Attributes:</h4>
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <input type="checkbox" id="select-all" name="options" value="select-all" />
            <label for="select-all" style="color: #4e73df"><strong>Select All</strong></label>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <form id="checkbox-form" class="container-fluid">
              <div class="d-flex p-2">
                <div class="flex-column p-2">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="ch1" name="Status" value="option1">
                  <label for="ch1">Status</label>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-column p-2">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="ch2" name="Last Updated Timestamp in Live Repo" value="option2">
                  <label for="ch2">Last </label>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-column p-2">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="ch3" name="Score" value="option3">
                  <label for="ch3">Score</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex-row  d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button type="button" id="show-more" class="btn btn-primary">Show More Options</button>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group options-container">
                <div id="options-group" class="d-flex p-2 d-none">
                  <div class="option flex-column p-2">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ch34" name="Sunday Opening Time" value="option34" />
                    <label for="ch34">opt1</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="option flex-column p-2">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ch35" name="Sunday Closing Time" value="option35" />
                    <label for="ch35">opt2</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="option flex-column p-2">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ch36" name="Monday Opening Time" value="option36">
                    <label for="ch36">opt3</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr />
              <h5 style="color: #4e73df">Japan Attributes: </h5>
              <hr>
              <div class="d-flex p-2">
                <div class="flex-column p-2">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="ch11" name="Primary Name (ja)" value="option11">
                  <label for="ch11">ja1</label>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-column p-2">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="ch12" name="Primary Name (Translation ja-Kana)" value="option12">
                  <label for="ch12">ja2</label>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-column p-2">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="ch13" name="options" value="option13">
                  <label for="ch13">ja3</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer mt-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div class="">
            <input type="submit" id="ok-btn" class="btn btn-success" value="Ok">
            <input type="button" id="cancel-btn" class="btn btn-danger" a-bs-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```